# Groovy map must be converted to JSON object with numerical object key

Tags: json, grails, flot

I am doing some processing with Groovy/Grails and the results are a map of type `<String, Float>`.

When returning the JSON object to the calling function (in this case, it's a flot diagram which requires [number,number] format), the key needs to be a number. This, in theory, is fine as my key to the map is a number in string form. I can't, however, figure out a way to create the JSON object with a numerical key.

I get results like this:

```
{"1":-9.814244910221474,"2":-9.710478606504552,"3":-9.636841089398253,"4":-9.524104819110796,"5":-9.522597036735684 ...}
```

instead of:

```
{1:-9.814244910221474,2:-9.710478606504552,3:-9.636841089398253,4:-9.524104819110796,5:-9.522597036735684 ...}
```

Does anyone know a way to force the JSON Map.encodeAsJSON() to produce an integer key? I've tried explicitly creating a map of type < integer,integer > before encoding it, and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike, Im looking at the json spec -- it appears that the keys must be strings.  You should handle this client side.

http://www.json.org/

Comment: Thanks, http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt mentions the JSON must be in numerical format, which is frustrating, so I guess I'll handle this client side.

Comment: @mike, note that according to the json spec, numbers CAN be in a an array.  I didn't go thru the entire api, but it seems they support arrays.  If they require an object key be a number, they are not json compliant.